# What happens when I free memory that may not exist in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, garbage-collection

Delphi doesn't have a garbage collector, so coming from a Java background this is a real pain in the neck.

Usually, to destroy some memory I won't use anymore I'd use:

```
if (SomeMemory <> nil) then
  SomeMemory.Free
```

What would happen if I don't check for `nil` before deleting?

Additionally, why someone would want to deal with all this "garbage collecting" by himself? Why among all the compiling options Delphi has, there is no `Garbage Collector = true`

Comment: The `SomeObject.Free` method itself does the `SomeObject <> nil` checking for you. You don't have to do it twice.

Comment: I saw it on a project I received and I am learning Delphi, I thought it was the way to go.

Comment: *Why among all the compiling options Delphi has, there is no Garbage Collector = true?* I have a question for you. Why can't you disable the garbage collector in Java?

Comment: A less flippant response is that for some types of application, a garbage collector places an unwelcome performance constraint on your app.

Comment: For global variables (like `var Form1: TForm1`), I suggest you use `FreeAndNil(Form1)`, in order to avoid the problem of having the variable pointing to an invalid reference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was thinking something similar, but in Delphi's way where you have to clean everything you use wouldn't it make code production, or maintenance much difficult.

Comment: First part of your Q doesn't make much sense too (but at least answerable). By "some memory" you clearly meant "some object", raw dynamic memory is a really different story.

Comment: [The philosophy behind not using GC as a conscious design choice](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/129530/what-are-the-complexities-of-memory-unmanaged-programming/129555#129555), which I posted (from my perspective as a Delphi developer) on Programmers.SE.  This might clear a few things up.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's not a "conscious design choice"; it's old tech. Even Wirth himself included GC in Oberon and lamented that people chose to commercialize his "flawed" earlier creations. No language created in the 21st century has neglected to include memory management. This is just something Delphi users invent ad hoc to try to convince themselves that Delphi is still the One True Way. I know because I used to defend the Interface/Implementations, Begin/Ends, and other stuff myself. Anything Delphi didn't have you didn't really need or it was actually better the old way.

Comment: @alcalde You are confusing "not using GC" with "not using any automatic memory management"

Comment: @Stefan: Please don't feed the trolls. Just flag him.

Comment: Why do people keep saying Delphi doesn't have a GC? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4442196/71200

Comment: @MasonWheeler Why? To me he has a valid point - although presented in a bit trollish way though. But sometimes I really miss the Tim Taylor grunt when someone talks about how awesome manual memory management is just to make the point. ;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [-XnoClassGC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1009045) ;)

Comment: @mjn One view of GC is that it is a way to view your machine as having infinite memory. The the collection part of GC is a way to fake infinite memory on a finite machine. `noClassGC` just stops faking!  ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code for `TObject.Free` looks like this :

```
procedure TObject.Free;
begin
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
end;
```

So there is no need to check for `nil`.  You can still get into trouble if you try to free an uninitialized variable, however, as this will result in an AV.  Checking for `nil` (or `Assigned`) obviously doesn't help you there either.  The compiler will warn you if you try to do this, however.

To answer your second question

> Why among all the compiling options Delphi has, there is no Garbage Collector = true

The simple answer is that Delphi does not have such a garbage collector.  Certain managed types (like strings, dynamic arrays, etc) implement compiler-managed automatic reference counting, and those objects are automatically freed when their reference counts fall to zero.  For all other unmanaged objects it is the responsibility of the developer to appropriately clean up object instances when they are no longer needed.

It's not a question of *wanting* to have to manage your application's memory, it's just a matter of course that you need to.

Comment: On iOS and Android, Delphi objects are compiler-managed types that use ARC.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is that a firemonkey thing, or is it platform specific?  All objects?  If you're compiling cross-platform do you have to have `IFDEF`s that conditionally free objects for a windows target?

Comment: Object ARC is a language feature of the mobile compilers only at this time, not the desktop compilers (though it might in the future). It applies to all `TObject` descendants.  Embarcadero has tried to make ARC transparent, by reimplementing `TObject.Free()` and `FreeAndNil()` to work under ARC, and introducing `TObject.DisposeOf()` on all platforms. If you want to write ARC-aware code (and sometimes you may need to), there are `{$DEFINE}`s for that. For the majority of code, you can keep using `Free()` and let ARC handle it as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Checking for `nil` before `Free` is redundant. If the reference is `nil`, then it's *already* safe to call `Free` on it. If the reference *isn't* `nil`, then the safety of calling `Free` on it is unchanged and depends entirely on whether the variable contains a valid reference.

For example:

```
SomeMemory := nil;
SomeMemory.Free; // This is safe.

SomeMemory := TObject.Create;
SomeMemory.Free; // This is safe
Assert(SomeMemory <> nil);
SomeMemory.Free; // This is an error (EInvalidOperation)
```

In the first block, we don't check whether the variable is null, and yet the call to `Free` is perfectly safe. It does nothing. In the second block, we see that the variable remains non-null, but calling `Free` on it yields an exception.

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty straight-forward way in Delphi to have (something like) garbage collection: use interface pointers. By using variables of a type ultimately derived from `IInterface` (or `IUnknown` which is basically the same thing), Delphi will keep close count of the references, and free/destroy/release the instance when the last reference is removed. Using interface pointers, apart from instance creation and a few other things, is almost identical to using object references.

In Nick Hodges' recent work [Coding In Delphi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1941266037), there's quite a bit on this programming technique, and its relations to abstraction, generics, unit testing and dependency injection.

Also [new versions of Delphi for other platforms will have ARC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) (automatic reference counting) on object references as well, operating like interfaces do now. (Obsoleting the Free method, but that's another story.)

Comment: Definitely. ARC is the future. Generational Garbage Collection (as in Java and C#) is rubbish, garbage, crap, and should never be added to Delphi.

Comment: Now, now, so negative! I've had one project where ARC wouldn't even cut it, since instances needed to get destroyed forcibly. We'd use 'smart' pointers that get an event raised by the destructor, and a kind of abortable locks when using them asynchronously. I should write a blog post with the details someday...

Answer (score 2):

You can always consult the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.Free) in order to answer such a question. Here it is, with my emphasis:

> Use Free to destroy an object. Free automatically calls the destructor if the object reference is not nil. Any object instantiated at run time that does not have an owner should be destroyed by a call to Free, so that it can be properly disposed of and its memory released. **Unlike Destroy, Free is successful even if the object is nil**; if the object was never initialized, Free would not result in an error.

Find a more complete discussion of the issue here: [Why should I not use "if Assigned()" before using or freeing things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628)